# Flutter - MissingPluginException al usar `invokeMethod`

Tags: flutter, dart

¡Hola!

Tengo un problema serio. Actualmente estoy usando el paquete de `flutter_background_service: ^0.2.6` para el tema de segundo plano de mi aplicación. Uso el segundo plano porqué lo requiero implementar con otro paquete de Bluetooth.

Este es mi código del archivo main.dart

```
import 'dart:async';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';
import 'package:flutter_background_service/flutter_background_service.dart';

Future<void> main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await initializeService();
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

Future<void> initializeService() async {
  final service = FlutterBackgroundService();
  await service.configure(
    androidConfiguration: AndroidConfiguration(
      onStart: onStart,
      autoStart: true,
      isForegroundMode: true,
    ),
    iosConfiguration: IosConfiguration(
      autoStart: true,
      onForeground: onStart,
      onBackground: onIosBackground,
    ),
  );
}

void onIosBackground() {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  print('FLUTTER BACKGROUND FETCH');
}

Future<void> onStart() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();

  MethodChannel flutterBle = const MethodChannel('****/ble_handle');
  final String value = await flutterBle.invokeMethod("test");

  final service = FlutterBackgroundService();
  service.onDataReceived.listen((event) {
    if (event!["action"] == "setAsForeground") {
      service.setForegroundMode(true);
      return;
    }

    if (event["action"] == "setAsBackground") {
      service.setForegroundMode(false);
    }

    if (event["action"] == "stopService") {
      service.stopBackgroundService();
    }
  });

  // bring to foreground
  service.setForegroundMode(true);
  Timer.periodic(const Duration(seconds: 1), (timer) async {
    if (!(await service.isServiceRunning())) timer.cancel();
    service.setNotificationInfo(
      title: "My App Service",
      content: "Updated at ${DateTime.now()}",
    );

    print(value);

    service.sendData(
      {
        "current_date": DateTime.now().toIso8601String(),
        "device": "Android",
      },
    );
  });
}

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _MyAppState createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  String text = "Stop Service";
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: const Text('Service App'),
        ),
        body: Column(
          children: [
            StreamBuilder<Map<String, dynamic>?>(
              stream: FlutterBackgroundService().onDataReceived,
              builder: (context, snapshot) {
                if (!snapshot.hasData) {
                  return const Center(
                    child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
                  );
                }

                final data = snapshot.data!;
                String? device = data["device"];
                DateTime? date = DateTime.tryParse(data["current_date"]);
                return Column(
                  children: [
                    Text(device ?? 'Unknown'),
                    Text(date.toString()),
                  ],
                );
              },
            ),
            ElevatedButton(
              child: const Text("Foreground Mode"),
              onPressed: () {
                FlutterBackgroundService()
                    .sendData({"action": "setAsForeground"});
              },
            ),
            ElevatedButton(
              child: const Text("Background Mode"),
              onPressed: () {
                FlutterBackgroundService()
                    .sendData({"action": "setAsBackground"});
              },
            ),
            ElevatedButton(
              child: Text(text),
              onPressed: () async {
                final service = FlutterBackgroundService();
                var isRunning = await service.isServiceRunning();
                if (isRunning) {
                  service.sendData(
                    {"action": "stopService"},
                  );
                } else {
                  service.start();
                }

                if (!isRunning) {
                  text = 'Stop Service';
                } else {
                  text = 'Start Service';
                }
                setState(() {});
              },
            ),
          ],
        ),
        floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
          onPressed: () {
            FlutterBackgroundService().sendData({
              "hello": "world",
            });
          },
          child: const Icon(Icons.play_arrow),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Este es mi código del archivo MainActivity.kt

```
package ****

import io.flutter.embedding.android.FlutterActivity
import io.flutter.embedding.engine.FlutterEngine
import io.flutter.plugin.common.MethodChannel

class MainActivity: FlutterActivity() {
    private var BLE_HANDLE = "****/ble_handle"
    private lateinit var channel: MethodChannel;

    override fun configureFlutterEngine(flutterEngine: FlutterEngine) {
        super.configureFlutterEngine(flutterEngine)

        channel = MethodChannel(flutterEngine.dartExecutor.binaryMessenger, BLE_HANDLE)

        channel.setMethodCallHandler { call, result ->
            if(call.method == "test") {
                result.success("Hola Mundo. Pasamos la prueba.")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Si intentan correr este código debería hacerlo sin problemas.

Si usan el invokeMethod ya dentro el State, este funciona bien, trayendo el resultado deseado. No he podido encontrar qué problema ocurre aquí.

NOTA: Intente de igual modo realizar esto en vez de Kotlin, Java, pero me encuentro en el mismo punto de error.

Comment: Intentaste con un futurebuilder al inicio? Mostrar un cargando por primera vez mientras ejecutas la llamada?

Comment: Hola @diegoveloper, lo qué pasa con el código es qué este se está ejecutando dentro un modo de segundo plano, dónde este en sí recibe cierta data y es constantemente (Hablamos de nuevos datos cada segundo).

Requiero escuchar estos nuevos datos pero antes debo transformarlos pasandolos a mi código de Java...

Actualicé el post lo qué realmente necesito, agradezco y le des un ojo.

Comment: ok, intentaste con un flutter clean , paraste y volviste a correr el app? para ver los cambios cada vez que hagas cambios en nativo necesitas detener el app, el hot-reload ni hot restart funcionan

Comment: Hola @diegoveloper, tal cual cómo lo comentas lo hice.

Comment: puedes mostrar el bloque de código que contiene void main, antes de llamar a runApp

Comment: Editado, por favor revisa.

Comment: en que parte invocas al method channel? en el initializeService? agrega ese detalle, en que parte usas ese background service tambien

Comment: Hola, dentro mi función transformData() qué también ha sido compartido su código. Y no, no se inicializada dentro del initializeService. Esa función es llamada por otra función qué recibe los datos, transformData() lo qué hace es comunicarse con mi código Java para desencriptar dichos datos y así darles valor.

Comment: es que no vemos en que parte llamas a transformData, mientras más detalles añadas será más fácil ayudar

Comment: @diegoveloper, listo.

Comment: pero quién llama a callServices? lo mejor sería que crees un proyecto nuevo, con solo esa conexión (sin firebase ni nada), solo eso, para ver en que falla, luego lo subes a github, no estoy seguro si es posible llamar a código nativo desde el background service, ya que es un isolate si no me equivoco, quizás solo es código dart.

Comment: Hola @diegoveloper, tristemente el resto de código es privado por politicas de la empresa. Igualmente muchas gracias por la ayuda, seguiré en investigación buscando el camino correcto, ten un feliz día.

Comment: no necesitas exponer ningún código, crea uno nuevo, agregas el plugin de background, llamas a un método en nativo que solo diga hello world y listo.

Comment: muevelo al stackoverflow español, sino te lo van a borrar del inglés xD

Comment: @diegoveloper, este post ha sido actualizado, gracias

Comment: si lo vi, hmmm algo me late que se está cruzando los canales cuando llamas al onStart` dentro del otro plugin, veo también varios issues abiertos relacionados a eso.
Lo que yo haría sería un fork del plugin `flutter_background_service`y ahí mismo crearía mi implementación nativa, entonces ya no tendrías problemas con llamar a otro canal nativo, sino directamente con ese background service.

Comment: Hola @diegoveloper, mi solución fue crear una API qué sólo me parse los datos con el código Java, funcionó de maravillas. Al fin y cabo mate dos pajaros de un sólo tiro con está solución. (Android & IOs)

Answer (score 0):

Intentaste poner en el main esta línea de código

```
WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
```

Y después de esto poner el resto del código que quieres que se ejecute luego de que se inicializa la aplicación:

```
    const bleHandle = MethodChannel('****/ble_handle');

    final args = {'data': event};
    final res = await bleHandle.invokeMethod('getActivityData', 
    args);
```

Comment: Hola. Esto funciona, pero no para mi caso de uso. Por favor mira la última edición realizada a esta duda, gracias por tu respuesta.

Answer (score 0):

Actualmente el complemento `flutter_background_service:` en la versión ^0.2.6 genera conflictos al momento de invocar el código externo teniendo un cruze de ambos canales.

Mi solución para este caso fue crear una API con SpringBoot el cúal me reciba el arreglo y me lo devuelve desencriptado, teniendo soporte tanto para Android cómo para IOs.

Otra solución hallada por @diegoveloper es crear un fork del complemento y crear una implementación nativa qué corrija este problema qué hasta la fecha de hoy no ha sido solucionada.